# Pthread_join não está funcionando como deveria para popular um array em C

Tags: c, pthreads

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

//declaração das variáveis globais
float *x;
float *y;
float *z;
pthread_mutex_t *mutexes;

typedef struct
{
    float* vetor;
    unsigned int posInicial;
    unsigned int posFinal;
    unsigned int contMutexThread;
} Thread_preenche;

typedef struct
{
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* z;
    unsigned int posInicial;
    unsigned int posFinal;
    unsigned int contMutexThread;
} Thread_soma;

void *preencheVetores(void *argPtr){
    Thread_preenche *thread_p = (Thread_preenche*)argPtr;
    unsigned int inicio = thread_p->posInicial;
    unsigned int final = thread_p->posFinal;

    for(;inicio <= final; inicio++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexes[thread_p->contMutexThread]);
        thread_p->vetor[inicio] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/1.0);
        printf("x[%u] e o valor é: %f \n", inicio, x[inicio]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexes[thread_p->contMutexThread]);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    //obtendo o tamanho do vetor e o número de threads que o usuário deseja
    int tamanho_vetor;
    int n;
    while (1){
        printf("Digite o tamanho do vetor: ");
        scanf("%d", &tamanho_vetor);
        printf("Digite o número de threads: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (tamanho_vetor % n != 0){
              printf("O número de threads deve ser múltiplo do tamanho do vetor. \n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    //inicialização dos vetores
    x =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);
    y =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);
    z =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);
    mutexes = (pthread_mutex_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)*n);
    int divisao_vetor[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        divisao_vetor[i] = ((tamanho_vetor/n)*(i));
    }
    pthread_t thread[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutexes[i],NULL);
        Thread_preenche thread_preenche = {
            .vetor = &x[0],
            .posInicial = (divisao_vetor[i]),
            .posFinal = divisao_vetor[i+1]-1,
            .contMutexThread = i
        };
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, preencheVetores, &(thread_preenche));
        //jeito errado, o join logo em seguida do create da thread.
        //pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    //Assim seria o jeito certo de fazer, o join sendo depois
    //mas não está funcionando.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    free(mutexes);

    #ifdef _WIN32
        system("pause");
    #else __linux__
        system("read -p 'Press Enter to continue...\n' key");
    #endif
    
   return 0;
}

void *somaVetores(void* argPtr);
```

Crio várias threads, cada uma para popular uma parte do vetor.
Se eu fizer do jeito errado que é fazer o join logo depois do create das threads dentro de um for, desse jeito:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, preencheVetores, &(thread_preenche));
pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
```

Eu tenho o resultado esperado, com todos os campos populados. Mas, foi removida toda concorrência das threads, oque não é desejado.

Se eu aplico o join nas threads depois que todas elas foram criadas, desssa forma:

```
//abstraindo o for que cria as threads.
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, preencheVetores, &(thread_preenche));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}
```

Eu não tenho o resultado desejado, são populado apenas os últimos elementos do array, como base na divisão que fiz de acordo com o número de threads, é como se todas as threads estivessem populando o mesmo range do array, embora tivesse definido ranges diferentes para cada thread popular o array. Porque isso está acontecendo ? Onde estou errado ?

Como exemplo, eu tenho o seguinte resultado (x é o array que estou populando):

```
Digite o tamanho do vetor: 32
Digite o número de threads: 4
x[24] e o valor é: 0.840188 
x[25] e o valor é: 0.394383 
x[26] e o valor é: 0.783099 
x[27] e o valor é: 0.798440 
x[28] e o valor é: 0.911647 
x[29] e o valor é: 0.197551 
x[30] e o valor é: 0.335223 
x[31] e o valor é: 0.768230 
x[24] e o valor é: 0.277775 
x[25] e o valor é: 0.553970 
x[26] e o valor é: 0.477397 
x[27] e o valor é: 0.628871 
x[28] e o valor é: 0.364784 
x[29] e o valor é: 0.513401 
x[30] e o valor é: 0.952230 
x[31] e o valor é: 0.916195 
x[24] e o valor é: 0.635712 
x[25] e o valor é: 0.717297 
x[26] e o valor é: 0.141603 
x[27] e o valor é: 0.606969 
x[28] e o valor é: 0.016301 
x[29] e o valor é: 0.242887 
x[30] e o valor é: 0.137232 
x[31] e o valor é: 0.804177 
x[24] e o valor é: 0.156679 
x[25] e o valor é: 0.400944 
x[26] e o valor é: 0.129790 
x[27] e o valor é: 0.108809 
x[28] e o valor é: 0.998924 
x[29] e o valor é: 0.218257 
x[30] e o valor é: 0.512932 
x[31] e o valor é: 0.839112
```

Comment: Vale mencionar que o mesmo problema acontece se eu simplismente não utilizar pthread_join() nenhum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no programa, mas o principal deles que causa este
comportamento é a delcaração e inicialização da struct `Thread_preenche`
dentro do looping.

Apesar da estrutura estar declarada dentro do looping, o compilador não aloca
memória para uma nova estrutura a cada iteração, portanto ela é tratada como
se fosse declarada apenas uma vez fora do looping.

Com isso, todas as *threads* são inicializadas com o último valor colocado
na struct, gerando a saída apenas com "os últimos valores".

A solução para este problema é declarar um *array* de estruturas
`Thread_preenche` e inicializar cada *thread* com a sua própria estrutura:

```
Thread_preenche thread_preenche[n];
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){                
    thread_preenche[i].vetor = &x[0];
    thread_preenche[i].posInicial = (divisao_vetor[i]);
    thread_preenche[i].posFinal = divisao_vetor[i+1]-1;
    thread_preenche[i].contMutexThread = i;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexes[i],NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, preencheVetores, &(thread_preenche[i]));
...
```

---

Outras melhorias que podem ser feitas, **dependendo do objetivo do programa**:

1. Não faz sentido declarar uma trava *mutex* para cada *thread*. O
   objetivo da trava é bloquear as demais *threads* durante o acesso a um
   recurso compartilhado (ex: um arquivo, um dispositivo, memória compartilhada,
   etc.), portanto a trava precisa ser única por **recurso** e todas elas,
   compartilhadas entre as *threads*. No caso do seu programa, se o objetivo for
   atualizar apenas a memória, como já há uma divisão do vetor para cada
   *thread*, a trava não é necessária, entretanto, o `printf` acessa um
   dispositivo de I/O e, neste caso, talvez faça sentido utilizar **uma**
   trava para acessá-lo.
2. Pode não ser necessário pré-calcular a divisão do vetor no *array*
   `divisao_vetor`, pois ele pode ser calculado diretamente dentro do looping
   que cria as *threads*. Porém, se o programa for apenas um exemplo de um
   sistema mais complexo, este armazenamento pode fazer sentido.

Segue uma versão otimizada e comentada do programa da pergunta,
apenas como exemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

//declaração das variáveis globais
float *x;
float *y;
float *z;

// AQUI => Cria apenas um mutex, compartilhado entre as threads
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

typedef struct
{
    float* vetor;
    unsigned int posInicial;
    unsigned int posFinal;
    unsigned int contMutexThread;
} Thread_preenche;

typedef struct
{
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* z;
    unsigned int posInicial;
    unsigned int posFinal;
    unsigned int contMutexThread;
} Thread_soma;

void *preencheVetores(void *argPtr){
    Thread_preenche *thread_p = (Thread_preenche*)argPtr;
    unsigned int inicio = thread_p->posInicial;
    unsigned int final = thread_p->posFinal;
    
    for(;inicio <= final; inicio++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        thread_p->vetor[inicio] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/1.0);
        printf("x[%u] e o valor é: %f \n", inicio, x[inicio]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    //obtendo o tamanho do vetor e o número de threads que o usuário deseja
    int tamanho_vetor;
    int n;
    while (1){
        printf("Digite o tamanho do vetor: ");
        scanf("%d", &tamanho_vetor);
        printf("Digite o número de threads: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (tamanho_vetor % n != 0){
            printf("O número de threads deve ser múltiplo do tamanho do vetor. \n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    //inicialização dos vetores
    x =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);
    y =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);
    z =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*tamanho_vetor);

    // AQUI => Excluído a declaração do vetor de travas e divisão
    //
    //    mutexes = (pthread_mutex_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)*n);
    //    int divisao_vetor[n+1];
    //    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    //        divisao_vetor[i] = ((tamanho_vetor/n)*(i));
    //    }
    //
    // AQUI => Calcula o tamanho do job de cada thread
    int num_job = tamanho_vetor / n;
    
    // AQUI => precisa declarar um parâmetro para cada thread para
    //         não sobrescrever os valores
    Thread_preenche thread_preenche[n];

    // AQUI => Inicializa apenas um MUTEX
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    pthread_t thread[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        // AQUI => Inicializa cada parâmetro separadamente e já
        // calcula o job de cada thread
        thread_preenche[i].vetor = &x[0];
        thread_preenche[i].posInicial = i*num_job;
        thread_preenche[i].posFinal = i*num_job+num_job-1;
        thread_preenche[i].contMutexThread = i;
        
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, preencheVetores, &thread_preenche[i]);
    }
    
    //Assim seria o jeito certo de fazer, o join sendo depois
    //mas não está funcionando.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    //free(mutexes);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

#ifdef _WIN32
    system("pause");
#else
    system("read -p 'Press Enter to continue...\n' key");
#endif
    return 0;
}

void *somaVetores(void* argPtr);
```